# memcpy copying the wrong number of bytes

Tags: c, memcpy

1.I have the following structure.

```
typedef struct
{ unsigned int ibaseRecord;
unsigned int irecordNumber;
unsigned char brecordType;
unsigned char  brevision;
unsigned int ipageNumber;
unsigned int ireserve1;
unsigned int ireserve2;
unsigned int ireserve3;
unsigned short scrc16;
} DATABASEPAGEHEADER_TypeDef;
```

I also have following byte buffer storing an array.

```
char  msg_response[]={0x9A,0x17,0x00,0x00,0x17,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x04,0x02,0x9F,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x23,0xEA,0x4A,0x86};
```

Using memcpy, I expect to map the buffer into the structure.

```
 DATABASEPAGEHEADER_TypeDef * varPageHeader;
 varPageHeader=(DATABASEPAGEHEADER_TypeDef*)malloc(sizeof(DATABASEPAGEHEADER_TypeDef));
 memcpy(varPageHeader,msg_response,sizeof(DATABASEPAGEHEADER_TypeDef));
```

However, the result messes up. Here is the inspection I made using gdb (explore the struct). Things were fine until the ipageNumber, which I expected to have value 0x0000009f.And also later in ireserveX (x=1,2,3).

```
ibaseRecord = 0x179a .. (Value of type 'unsigned int')
irecordNumber = 0x17 .. (Value of type 'unsigned int')
brecordType = 0x4 .. (Value of type 'unsigned char')
brevision = 0x2 .. (Value of type 'unsigned char')
ipageNumber = 0x0 .. (Value of type 'unsigned int')
ireserve1 = 0x0 .. (Value of type 'unsigned int')
ireserve2 = 0x0 .. (Value of type 'unsigned int')
ireserve3 = 0xea230000 .. (Value of type 'unsigned int')
scrc16 = 0x864a .. (Value of type 'short unsigned int') 
(gdb) print sizeof(unsigned int)
 $7 = 0x4
```

Does anyone have solution to it?

problem solved. It was the struct alignment problem. Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: A solution to what problem? Maybe [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) is something to read…

Comment: How are you printing the numbers?

Comment: Run this: `sizeof(unsigned int)`.  Is it 8?  That seems awfully large.

Comment: 0x0 is the same as 0x0000 is the same as 0x00000000 -- they're all zero.  How you got that third number to print the way it did, I don't know, but it's not because memcpy is messing up.

Comment: It's `typedef`, not `type define`. No, don't just fix that; copy-and-paste your actual code, including the code that prints the results; without that, we can only guess what the problem might be. http://sscce.org/. And while you're fixing that, please correct your title by changing `memcp` to `memcpy`.

Comment: Yep, show the real code, including how you print the values.

Comment: Show the output statement and explain what you expected. This happened on my machine as well, but I expected it to appear the same because I coded it that way.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune I expected the code will fill the three nums in the struct, 4 bytes for each

Comment: @mafso sorry for the typo. I think it is not the endianness problem. I have taken it into consideration. I will paste the real code here.

Comment: @HarryQ It worked as it ought to then. On a little endian machine, 0x12345678 turns into 0x78563412 with a 4-byte value. The first 8 bytes are all 0, so num1 and num2 are 0. The remaining 4 bytes are, in little endian order, 0x32, 0, 0, 0x12. Really. Try `int n = 0x32000012; char buf[4]; memcpy(buf, &n, sizeof n); for (n = 0; n < sizeof buf; ++n) printf("0x%02x\n", buf[n]);`. You simply did the opposite operation. If you want to map things in big endian order, you must convert each value to little endian on a little endian machine.

Comment: The problem is *structure alignment* -- see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979791/c-data-structures-alignment

Comment: Your real code is *nothing like* the fake code you first posted...

Comment: @ChronoKitsune I am using it on the little endian machine. Because the data flowing into the buffer is already little endianned, I just need to copy the content to a desired struct, and it should be displaying the correct number.

Comment: @Boann I tried to make it simple to read. The current code is actually extracted from multiple functions, among which a lot of passing was done.

Comment: the 4 bytes over maybe just padding for structure alignment. You should post all the printing code or no one will understand why the printed size is different

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The struct members are being aligned to units of their size. So the struct has a 2-byte gap between `unsigned char brevision` and `unsigned int iPageNumber`, so that `iPageNumber` starts at a 4-byte boundary. I'm not aware of a standards-compliant way to remove that padding, but for GCC you can specify `__attribute__((packed))`:

```
typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) {
    unsigned int ibaseRecord;
    unsigned int irecordNumber;
    unsigned char brecordType;
    unsigned char brevision;
    unsigned int ipageNumber;
    unsigned int ireserve1;
    unsigned int ireserve2;
    unsigned int ireserve3;
    unsigned short scrc16;
} DATABASEPAGEHEADER_TypeDef;
```

If you want to make this properly portable though; don't use that attribute, or memcpy at all. Instead, initialize your struct fields individually from the byte data, and consider using specifically sized data types like `uint32_t` instead of `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple things wrong here

1) struct can include packing as pointed out by @Boann.

2) Byte endianness. When dealing with raw byte data you should be aware of it's endianness.
in little endian mode, a word with value `0xABCDEF00` is stored as sequence of 4 bytes `(0x00, 0xEF, 0xCD, 0xAB)` while in big endian mode is stored as `(0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF, 0x00)`.

Error due to 1) is unpredictable. However, You can fix error caused by 2) as can be observed by the swapped bytes in the 1st and second unsigned ints. (Look at the pattern of values you sent and the values displayed by gdb and then look at the representation of the same value in little and big endian above).